# Is there a way to rename a bunch of bones at once?

Tags: rigging

I have a rig with a lot of bones, most of them are improperly named because I copy and pasted sections of the rig. Is there an addon or something that will make it easier to rename a group of bones, like if I select a bunch of bones, rename one, can I have the rest of them be renamed in series (with an index) based on the order I selected them in?

Comment: i don't know whether it can rename based on selection order, but did you try batch rename?

Comment: I'll try it out when i get the opportunity to do so again.